# What are the different types of spam that the Lightning Network is subject to?

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, spam

What are the different types of spam that the Lightning Network is subject to and what are the possible strategies for dealing with such spam?

Comment: I've unquoted this as this isn't a quote. It is just me writing what question Rusty is answering.

Answer (score 3):

> There are three types of spam problem in the Lightning Network. Let's
> call them "local","fast" and "slow".
>
> **Local spam** is someone sending or requesting too much data: that's a simple batter of code with rate limiting etc.
>
> **Fast spam** is sending many failed payments.  You can't tell what will succeed and you can't blame the sending peer (they may not be the
> source).  This attack is free since we only pay on success. The answer
> is to require an up-front payment but it has to be small (making sure
> your incentive is to succeed) and it should not leak information on
> where you are in the path.  I've been unable to find a scheme I'm
> happy with though, see my latest attempt [here](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2019-November/002275.html).
>
> **Slow spam** is sending a long-lived payment. This consumes capacity > 1000x expected for a normal payment and is similarly free (if you fail). The only solution I like here is to penalize slow payments by
> requiring [proof-of-channel closure](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2015-August/000135.html) but you can't always tell if
> the payment was really in the channel and what if the close
> transaction pays super-low fees / conflicts?  You need a Merkle tree
> of claimed HTLCs, plus onion unwrapping, agreement on valid closes,
> handling of fake Merkle trees... all possible but real work.
>
> Summary: We can mitigate some attacks but real fixes need spec
> improvements and implementation.  More attention from Smarter People
> Than Me (hi!) will help us here.

This question was answered by Rusty Russell on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/rusty_twit/status/1308566351556964354?s=20).

Comment: Hi Michael, love the content you have been putting up here lately. Please be sure to format quotes as such when you copy them. Stuff like "solution I like" become a bit confusing when it's not clear that the whole answer is a quote.

Comment: Sure. Will do. Thanks for the feedback!